# Python sparse matrix set diag to 1

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix

I would like to set the diagonal entries of a sparse matrix (in Python) equal to 1 iff the sum of the row elements is equal to 0. In other words, I would like to set A_ii = 1 iff sum_j A_ij = 0. 
Does anyone know a way to do so without iterating on the row since my matrix is very large ?

Thank you in advance, 
bests

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

# example matrix
A = np.array([[-1, 1, 0],
              [2, 0, -2],
              [0, 0, 3]])

i = (A.sum(axis=1) == 0)
A[i, i] = 1

# array([[1, 1, 0],
#        [2, 1, -2],
#        [0, 0, 3]])
```

**Edit**: for a sparse matrix you basically do the same as above. The difference is that `A.sum(1)` now has shape (N, 1), not (N,) as for numpy array, so we have to flatten it.

```
# import scipy.sparse as sp
# A = sp.csr_matrix(A)  # I suppose that your matrix is in csr format
i = np.asarray(A.sum(axis=1) == 0).ravel()
A[i, i] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you @AndyK for your reply. Unfortunately, my matrix is really large and sparse so I have to work with sparse format due to memory space...  Would you have another idea ?

Comment: Did this work with your sparse matrix? What format is it in?